# messageDialog doesn't close - java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to display a "Game Over" message in my game.

After pressing OK I want the message dialog to close and also the gui itself to close(I use `JFrame`).

I tried using

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game is over", "InfoBox: GameOver", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

But when OK is pressed, the message dialog doesn't close even though from what I read it's supposed to. How can I change that?

Also, how can I close the whole gui after pressing the OK button on the messageDialog?

Here is the code :

```
 if (isGameOver()) { 
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game is Over", "InfoBox: GameOver", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
 }
```

Comment: the part regarding the message dialog is only this:
if (isGameOver()) {        
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game is Over", "InfoBox: GameOver",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

Comment: The rest of the code is needed to reproduce the problem. If you want to add information, please edit directly the question.

Comment: I agree with @YassinHajaj. Besides, if a frame doesn't close on itself, you should check the console output. Maybe an Exception was thrown which interrupted the event thread of the frame causing it not to be able to close.

Comment: You are likely blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing from update the UI

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in the end adding System.exit(0) like this:

```
if (isGameOver()) { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game is Over", "InfoBox: GameOver", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    System.exit(0); 
}
```

After pressing ok it closes the whole gui.

Comment: I don't want to close the full gui , its not an perfect solution.